# Cannot invoke 'ISO8601DateFormatter' with no arguments in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdateformatter

When converting my Swift2 project to Swift3, I get the following error in XCode, on the following code:

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
```

> Cannot invoke 'ISO8601DateFormatter' with no arguments in Swift3

In Playground this compiles fine.  Does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this?  All the classes that produce the error, also have Alamofire imported.  Not sure if this can have an effect.

Comment: just to remind that this API is only available for iOS 10.x or more recent (in future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 let date = Date()
    let isoformatter = ISO8601DateFormatter.init()
    let timeStr = isoformatter.string(from: date)

    // Generete Date from string that being generated
    let dateFromString = isoformatter.date(from: timeStr)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to get to the root of the problem.  When I used your code, the compiler compiled with error, "Ambiguous use of init()".  In a previous version of the code, it had ISO8601DateFormatter.h and .m file included in the code.  That was removed, but it was still included in the bridging-header file.  Fixed now.  Thanks